# error in flutter doctor, win 10 SDK unable to locate

Tags: flutter, sdk, flutter-doctor

i try all option but i can´t get it work.
run in WIN11
[image: Flutter Doctor -v]

[image: vusual basic instalation.]

Last Update. still same error

[image: last update]

Answer (score 1):

You have the right package, but you still need another component.
As I can see from the image, you have the **Windows 11 SDK** but not the **Windows 10 SDK**.

Download it and run again `flutter doctor`.

[image]

Comment: i got same error :(.

Comment: Try installing **Windows 10 Preview SDK (10.0.19041.0)**, that's the one I currently have.

Comment: installed it i got same error again, maybe a flutter doctor error.